# scapy code: srp(Ether()/ARP(pdst="192.168.0.100"), timeout=1, inter=0.2) sometimes can receive the answers, normally can't

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy, arp, ether

These are all I wanna send out and get the answers. However, only sometimes can get the correct receive packets, usually can't.

```
srp(Ether()/ARP(pdst="192.168.0.100", hwsrc="xxxxxx"), timeout=2)
```

this problem is driving me crazy, anybody can help to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's simple: your host doesn't always answer to the ARP requests.

Certain devices tend to do this more than others. For instance iPhones devices tend not to, and only answer to ARP when they are connecting to the network (short timeframes) whereas Windows / Linux computers tend to answer everything.

Comment: I think you gave me the exactly correct reason. And think you so much !!! However, I wanna know why my iphone doesn't always answer ARP requests. I cannot find the reason after searched both English and Chinese related articles. Really hope you can give me some hint. Appreciate your answer anyway.

Comment: I didn't find an official explanation. That's based on my experience with playing around with ARP & IPhones. They also ignore gratuitous ARPs by default for instance. It's probably for security reasons: it makes them way less vulnerable to ARP poisoning.

Comment: It could also be that they turn off some services when not used (ARP handling ?) to spare some battery.