# Python ARP scanner

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, network-programming, scapy

This code is an arp scanner, it scans all hosts on the network except phones.
Program print only ip and mac addresses of computers, not phones

Nobody knows why this happens?
Thanks

```
import scapy.all as scapy

class scan:
    def Arp(self, ip):
        self.ip = ip
        print(ip)
        arp_r = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
        br = scapy.Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')
        request = br/arp_r
        answered, unanswered = scapy.srp(request, timeout=1)
        print('\tIP\t\t\t\t\tMAC')
        print('_' * 37)
        for i in answered:
            ip, mac = i[1].psrc, i[1].hwsrc
            print(ip, '\t\t' + mac)
            print('-' * 37)

arp = scan() # create an instance of the class
arp.Arp('192.168.0.1/24') # call the method
```

Comment: How did you determine that "phones" are not scanned?

Comment: You see any errors?

Comment: "_I tried to "read the entire Internet"_" ARP is only only the local LAN. You cannot get ARP for other networks, and, indeed, not all networks use ARP.

Comment: With this phrase I wanted to say that I read the documentation of everything on the Internet

Comment: Sorry for the clumsy translation, I'm not English

Comment: How did you determine that "phones" are not scanned?
Program print only ip and mac addresses of computers, not phones

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57017630/5459467
Some phones simply don't answer to ARP pings, mostly iPhones.

That's not necessarily explained anywhere, and could have multiple explanations such as:
- security concerns
- battery management

They will also tend to ignore gratuitous ARP. The only actions you can actually do is to answer faster than the router when they perform actual ARP requests, or simply sniff passively all ARP requests.

Comment: And how then do the scanners in the playmarket work?  They perfectly define all the hosts on the network.And networkdiscover are works too.

Comment: You can use the Bonjour service to discover Apple devices.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the interface your device is using.

```
answered, unanswered = srp(Ether(dst = "FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF") / ARP(pdst = ip), timeout = 1, iface = 'wlp1s0', inter = 0.1)
```